# How to split a nested list by \n but skip the the first one? Python

Tags: python, list, split, nested-lists

```
my_list = [
    'Rob Kardashian\n 00052369 1987-03-17 Reality Star\nBrooke Barry 00213658 2001-03-30 TikTok Star',
    'John Lennon\n 02578913 1940-10-09 Singer',
    'Bae De Leon\n 00896351 1997-08-02 Volleyball Player\nJonas Blue 02369785 1990-08-02 Music Producer\nAlbert Einstein 65231478 1879-03-14',
    'Robert Downey\n Jr 23897410 1965-04-04 Actor'
]
```

I have a list above and I split it by numbers as below.

```
my_list_new = [re.split('\s(?=\d)|(?<=\d)\s', i) for i in my_list]
```

Output:

```
[
    [ 'Rob Kardashian\n', '00052369','1987-03-17', 'Reality Star\nBrooke Barry', '00213658', '2001-03-30', 'TikTok Star'],
    ['John Lennon\n', '02578913', '1940-10-09', 'Singer'],
    ['Bae De Leon\n', '00896351', '1997-08-02', 'Volleyball Player\nJonas Blue', '02369785', '1990-08-02', 'Music Producer\nAlbert Einstein', '65231478', '1879-03-14'], 
    ['Robert Downey\n Jr', '23897410', '1965-04-04', 'Actor']
]
```

The next step: I want to split the my_list_new by '\n' but skip the first one.

How to use the list comprehension to do the work?

Expected outputs:

```
[
    ['Rob Kardashian\n', '00052369', '1987-03-17', 'Reality Star', 'Brooke Barry', '00213658', '2001-03-30','TikTok Star'],
    ['John Lennon\n', '02578913', '1940-10-09', 'Singer'],
    ['Bae De Leon\n', '00896351', '1997-08-02', 'Volleyball Player', 'Jonas Blue','02369785', '1990-08-02', 'Music Producer', 'Albert Einstein', '65231478', '1879-03-14'],
    ['Robert Downey\n Jr', '23897410', '1965-04-04', 'Actor']
]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you post a desired output? I'm not totally sure if you want to skip the first element of the list or the first occurrence of `\n` on every loop

Comment: @Juan C please see the update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without `itertools`:

```
lst = [['Rob Kardashian\n','00052369','1987-03-17','Reality Star\nBrooke Barry','00213658','2001-03-30','TikTok Star'],
['John Lennon\n', '02578913', '1940-10-09', 'Singer'],
['Bae De Leon\n','00896351','1997-08-02','Volleyball Player\nJonas Blue','02369785','1990-08-02','Music Producer\nAlbert Einstein','65231478','1879-03-14'],['Robert Downey\n Jr', '23897410', '1965-04-04', 'Actor']]

lst = [sum(row, []) for row in [[l[:1], *[i.split('\n') for i in l[1:]]] for l in lst]]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(lst, width=250)
```

Prints:

```
[['Rob Kardashian\n', '00052369', '1987-03-17', 'Reality Star', 'Brooke Barry', '00213658', '2001-03-30', 'TikTok Star'],
 ['John Lennon\n', '02578913', '1940-10-09', 'Singer'],
 ['Bae De Leon\n', '00896351', '1997-08-02', 'Volleyball Player', 'Jonas Blue', '02369785', '1990-08-02', 'Music Producer', 'Albert Einstein', '65231478', '1879-03-14'],
 ['Robert Downey\n Jr', '23897410', '1965-04-04', 'Actor']]
```

Comment: Thank you. The answer solved my question very well! BTW, what is sum()?

Comment: @Jancos `sum()` is Python's builtin function https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sum It will return the sum of iterable as first parameter. Note the second parameter here, in this case `[]`, that's starting value.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the list elements, `split` on `\n`, flatten the nested lists using `itertools.chain`, and concatenate lists:

```
[l[:1] + list(itertools.chain(*[i.split('\n') for i in l[1:]])) for l in lst]
```

**Example:**

```
In [295]: lst = [['Rob Kardashian\n','00052369','1987-03-17','Reality Star\nBrooke Barry','00213658','2001-03-30','TikTok Star'], 
     ...: ['John Lennon\n', '02578913', '1940-10-09', 'Singer'], 
     ...: ['Bae De Leon\n','00896351','1997-08-02','Volleyball Player\nJonas Blue','02369785','1990-08-02','Music Producer\nAlbert Einstein','65231478','1879-03-14'],['Robert Downey\n Jr', '23897410', '19
     ...: 65-04-04', 'Actor']]                                                                                                                                                                              

In [296]: [l[:1] + list(itertools.chain(*[i.split('\n') for i in l[1:]])) for l in lst]                                                                                                                     
Out[296]: 
[['Rob Kardashian\n',
  '00052369',
  '1987-03-17',
  'Reality Star',
  'Brooke Barry',
  '00213658',
  '2001-03-30',
  'TikTok Star'],
 ['John Lennon\n', '02578913', '1940-10-09', 'Singer'],
 ['Bae De Leon\n',
  '00896351',
  '1997-08-02',
  'Volleyball Player',
  'Jonas Blue',
  '02369785',
  '1990-08-02',
  'Music Producer',
  'Albert Einstein',
  '65231478',
  '1879-03-14'],
 ['Robert Downey\n Jr', '23897410', '1965-04-04', 'Actor']]
```

Comment: You can keep the first element in the `chain` which might be nice if you wanted to keep the iterable together: `list(chain(l[:1], *[i.split('\n') for i in l[1:]])`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT - here it is with just a list comprehension, no imports required:

```py
[[inner_list[0]] + [split for item in inner_list[1:] for split in item.split("\n")] for inner_list in my_list]
```

This uses the idea from @heemayl that we can treat the first element specially and just split on all of the others, whether there is a `"\n"` or not. This makes all of those elements into lists, so we flatten each one with another nested for loop inside of the list comprehension. But this is really more comprehensions than you want to do at once...

ORIGINAL:

If you're willing to use for loops, you could do it like this:

```py
my_list = [
    [ 'Rob Kardashian\n', '00052369','1987-03-17', 'Reality Star\nBrooke Barry', '00213658', '2001-03-30', 'TikTok Star'],
    ['John Lennon\n', '02578913', '1940-10-09', 'Singer'],
    ['Bae De Leon\n', '00896351', '1997-08-02', 'Volleyball Player\nJonas Blue', '02369785', '1990-08-02', 'Music Producer\nAlbert Einstein', '65231478', '1879-03-14'], 
    ['Robert Downey\n Jr', '23897410', '1965-04-04', 'Actor']
]

for i, inner_list in enumerate(my_list):
    new_inner_list = []
    for j, item in enumerate(inner_list):
        if j > 0 and "\n" in item:
            new_inner_list.extend(item.split("\n"))
        else:
            new_inner_list.append(item)
    my_list[i] = new_inner_list
```

I don't know if this can be done with a list comprehension, though; the issue is that you'd need to unpack the lists you get from doing the split. Even if you *can* do it with a comprehension, though, I wouldn't recommend using those once your logic gets very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for finding a generic way, you may oneshot this with:

```
[re.split('\s(?=\d)|(?<=\d)\s|(?<!Rob Kardashian)\n', i) for i in my_list]
```